# How to use htmlparser2 in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, parsing, html-parsing

Does anyone know how to use htmlparser2 in the browser? I don't need to use node for this project and it seems like there's only an example of how to use it with nodeJS:

```
 var htmlparser = require("htmlparser2");
 var parser = new htmlparser.Parser({

  onopentag: function(name, attribs){
    if(name === "script" && attribs.type === "text/javascript"){
        console.log("JS! Hooray!");
    }
},

  ontext: function(text){
    console.log("-->", text);
 },

  onclosetag: function(tagname){
    if(tagname === "script"){
        console.log("That's it?!");
    }
  }
}, {decodeEntities: true});

  parser.write("Xyz <script type='text/javascript'>var foo = '<<bar>>';</ script>");

  parser.end();
```

[htmlparser2 Github](https://github.com/fb55/htmlparser2)

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://github.com/fb55/htmlparser2#how-does-this-module-differ-from-node-htmlparser) - specifically `this is intended to be used only with node`

Comment: @JaromandaX If you are talking about the section usage in browser, YES I read the documentation before to ask here.

Comment: so `this is intended to be used only with node` means nothing to you?

Comment: @JaromandaX You are wrong, this can be also used in browser look at this: https://github.com/tautologistics/node-htmlparser

Comment: @JaromandaX To be fair, it continues `(it runs on other platforms using browserify)` .

Comment: @JohannesJander - and there's the answer on how to run it in a browser - sometimes documentation is actually enough information, you don't need to get someone to do all the work for you on SO

Comment: `You are wrong,` - really ... so, you link to one library in the question, then suggest I am wrong by linking to a **different library** as a rebuttal ... can I rebut your assertion that I am wrong by linking to yet another library?

Comment: It's not a different library, this is the same repo with a different Github user account from what I can see.

Comment: @JohannesJander Thanks for the useful comment!

Comment: By the way, I am curious what the use-case is here. Why use a dog-slow HTML parser written in JS on a platform that provides a lightning fast forgiving native parser complete with an excellent API if you include jQuery?